# asp-page-handler returns "Input string was not in a correct format."

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, razor-pages

I'm working with razer pages and got a page with a few different submit buttons for different actions. For this case i'm using the asp tag helpers.

I got the following html markup:

```
<form method="post">
     <input type="hidden" asp-for="SelectedLicense.Licenseid" />
     <input class="btn btn-info" type="submit" value="Drucken" asp-page-handler="Printing" />
</form>
```

And i want to trigger the following method:

```
public IActionResult OnPostPrinting()
{
   //... Do Stuff
}
```

Basically i got the exact same setup on a different Page and it works fine. The only difference is that on that other page i got some more input fields.

Whenever i try to submit the button i get the following error:

```
FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

System.Number.StringToNumber(ReadOnlySpan<char> str, NumberStyles options, ref NumberBuffer number, NumberFormatInfo info, bool parseDecimal)
```

I tried to remove the hidden input field but it didn't change anything. Mabye i'm using the asp-page-handler wrong, but i looked it up in the docs and they are using it the exact same way. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the input string?

Comment: @tymtam when i'm looking at the query of the error it tells me that it's the Value "Printing" of the variable `handler`

Comment: "Printing" is not a number.

Comment: Can you provide in which line exactly the error thrown? The exception tells you that somewhere you're trying to parse string as numeric value, but doesn't work because passed string is not convertible to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are passing the wrong input to the StringToNumber.

You could put a breakpoint at the line that calles `StringToNumber` and work until the right input is passed in.

Comment: I just debugged through the process that happens when i'm clicking that form button and somehow it goes through my whole db model and my properties. I only want to call this single method, i thought this is what asp-page-handler is for. I'm new to razor, thank you for your help!

Comment: @EliasJohannes You are partly correct. The handler method will be selected, but the ModelBinder will attempt to bind incoming form values to all properties that are marked with `BindProperty` before the handler is executed.

Comment: Thank you a lot @MikeBrind! Brings some light in the dark

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i was using uncessary `[BindProperty]` tags in my Model which resulted in the Model getting called with null values and threw the exception. Deleting the tags solved my problem.